Gravitational waves from any metric?
First, to be clear, I know practically nothing on gravitational waves and finding their solutions. The most I know confidently is that they are found by expanding the metric in a weak field expansion via $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + \kappa h_{\mu\nu}$ where $\kappa^2 = 32\pi G$ (depending on your convention). With that out of the way, suppose I had a metric of the form
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = g_{tt}dt^2 + g_{rr}(dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin(\theta)^2d\phi^2) + 2g_{t\phi}dtd\phi
\end{equation}
for some metric components (if need be I can write them out fully). My question then is, am I able to get gravitational wave solutions out of this metric? Or does this metric appear too black hole-ish since it appears to be rotating?
If not, would it be valid to modify the metric in such a way that allows for wave propagation such as including a term $ds^2\supset 2h\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$ where $h$ is some component corresponding to a polarization mode? Or, perhaps a better question, what form must the metric be in order to reproduce something that has two polarization modes and can be interpreted as gravitational waves? Should I modify the metric above to include off-diagonal terms in $(r,\theta,\phi)$?
Thanks in advance for any help, or references to point me towards, or hints.

If your metric attains a flat metric near infinity, then you can try calculating the Weyl scalar $\psi_4$ . If it's non zero then it means the solution describes a gravitational wave

@KP99 I have never heard of $\psi_4$ (that's neat). Then should I use the given definition (taken straight from Wikipedia) $\psi_4 = C_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}n^\alpha\bar{m}^\beta n^\gamma \bar{m}^\delta$, or the other definition in terms the plus and cross polarizations of gravitational waves? (I first need to show that the metric in question is asymptotically flat near infinity).

Yeah the expression is correct. Normally gravitational wave can mean a generic propagation of disturbance and not just the wave equation (which is defined on a given background). If your spacetime is asymptotically flat, then $\psi_4$ actually gives an invariant indicator that there is gravitational wave

@KP99 how would I write then the null tetrads in $\psi_4$?

The metric perturbation is applied to flat spacetime. Are you asking about the form of gravitational waves close to a source? In which case $g_{\mu \nu} \neq \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$.

Since the metric is reminiscent of the kerr metric, you can look at The Mathematical Theories of Black Holes by S.Chandrasekhar... there are discussion on the Newman Penrose formalism for kerr and other BH solutions
